# How to preserve line endings while edit patch?

Tags: git, sublimetext, patch

I use `rsub` on remote host and `sublime` on local to edit patches:
Remote:

```
$ env | grep EDITOR
EDITOR=rsub --port 52697
```

Local:

```
~/.ssh/config
...
RemoteForward 52697 127.0.0.1:52698
```

So when I put into index changes:

```
 $ EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' git add -p my_file
```

The `my_file` is opened in sublime but with unix line endings despite on `my_file` have windows line endings. So to escape next errors:

```
error: patch failed: my_file:1232
error: my_file: patch does not apply
```

I click on status bar at sublime and change `(LF)` to `(CRLF)`. But here I know that `my_file` has *windows line endings*.

How to configure `sublime` or `rmate` (rsub) to preserve original line endings?

Comment: What is the output of `git config core.autocrlf` on your remote host?

Comment: And out of curiosity, why are you editing things directly over SSH, instead of doing it locally and `git push`/`git pull`ing?

Comment: @ScottWeldon: I do not like console editor, so I use `sublimetext`

Comment: Right, but is there a reason you can't keep a copy of the repo locally (and edit files with Sublime Text, stage, and commit, all locally) and then push to/pull from your remote server?

Comment: 1. I have no `config core.autocrlf`; 2. I have no DB locally so I need run scripts only on remote host.